# How can I target this HTML code individually in CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors

I have two sets of text that need to be inline with each other but at the moment one is placed higher than the other. The two sets of text share the same CSS code so when I edit it, both are affected. However, I would like to target only one of the text; Is there a way of doing this?

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
<?

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM stock");
while($obj = $result->fetch_object())
{
    if($obj->id&1)
    echo "<ul>";

?>
<li class="<?=$obj->orientation=='landscape'?'landscape':'portrait'?>" id="list">
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/<?=$obj->description=='unframed'?$obj->poster_no:$obj->poster_no.'_frame'?>.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <h4><?= $obj->description=="unframed"?"Unframed Poster - 750mm x 500mm":"Framed Poster - 790mm x 540mm"?><br />&pound;<?=$obj->price?> each</h4>
</li>
```

The CSS code:

```
.mi-slider ul li h4 {
display: inline-block;
font-family: HelveticaNeueRegular;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 12px;
color: #a34235;
padding: 0 0 0;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: if($obj->id&1) <- I've never seen that before? oh, the name of the property?

Comment: A single ampersand (&) denotes a bitwise AND. This will evaluate to true if both sides of the expression have matching bits. The integer 1 has the least significant bit set and will evaluate to true for any odd number. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Ah, of course, I'm always forgetting about bitwise, such a clever thing it is too.  Goes to show I do not use it often enough. Thanks @Jo Are By

Comment: @iNeed_anAnswer **please accept some of your previous questions**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target the second list items H4, you can use the nth-child selector, as below:

```
.mi-slider ul li:nth-child(2) h4
{ your css }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use unique ID for each special element, then specify your CSS via '#' selector.

if the special CSS need to be applied to the first element,
consider using the ':first-child' selector. its cleaner.
but, if you want to target the second element (or later) consider that the 'nth-child' selector is not suported in older browser (like IE8)

Comment: He is using a while loop, ID must be unique in the document !

Comment: id="<?= "some_id_".$i++ ?>"

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
li:first-child h4
{
    your custum css
}
```

With this, the CSS rules only apply to the `h4` tag of first `li` instead of all `li`.